# Replace chars without String replace() Method

Tags: java, string

Write a method called `game`, which takes a normal word (parameter data type: `String`) and translates it into a word of the B Game. The B-Game works by adding a `b` plus the vocal repeat to each vowel (a, e, i, o, u) of a word.

Example:

- passed string: `play with me`
- returned string: `plabay wibith mebe`

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="play with me";
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
            if(chars[i]=='i' || chars[i]=='e' || chars[i]=='a' || chars[i]=='u' || chars[i]=='o' ) {
                list.add(i); // add position to list
            }
        }
        int size=chars.length+(list.size()*2);
        char [] charsNew= new char[size];

        for(int i=0;i<charsNew.length;i++) {
            for(int f=0;f<chars.length;f++) {

                charsNew[i]=chars[f];

            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(charsNew));
            }   
        }


    }
```

How I can do it without using `replace()`?

Comment: Your code does **not** use `replace()` - so what is your question?

Comment: Well, his code doesn't work correct and produces quite some mess. But why are you using a `List<Integer>` + `char[]` to build a `String` and not something more appropriate like a `StringBuilder` instead?

Comment: As @GhostCat pointed out, you do not use [`String::replace(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-). If your code is not working correctly, please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including test cases) and rephrase the title to reflect that you are looking for help debugging your code.

Comment: I can not use a string method or StringBuilder

Comment: Then use simple string concatenation to build the result string, which your compiler will probably optimize to use a Stringbuilder anyway.

Comment: @Abdessamad if you are not allowed to use any method of `String` then you have no possibility to query the `char`s the `String` is composed of. Therefore, the problem is not solvable under these constraints.

Comment: but how can i write my own method Replace ()?

Comment: @Abdessamad as I said before: under the given constraints ("do not use any method of `String` or `StringBuilder`"), the problem is not solvable. Please clarify what you are allowed to use and what not. If you want debug advice, please create a MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stream the characters of the string, and surround every vowel with `b`s:

```
Set<String> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"));

String s = "play with me";

String result =
    s.chars()
     .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
     .map(c -> vowels.contains(c) ? c + "b" + c : c)
     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Elegant, but not admissible as Java 101 assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you do not need the list you build while (basically) counting vowels. Simply count them using an integer (this will get the same result as building the list and computing its size), but is easier to understand and uses less resources.
Next allocate memory to build the new string, as in your example code. That's just fine.

Then fill the new string. This needs only one loop. I do not get your idea for the inner loop.

You need to remember  the index for the new string, this is not the loop counter, because sometimes it will be incremented by 3 instead of 1 if a vowel is encountered. The loop iterates over the unmodified input string.
Copy the next character and increment your index into the next string by 1. 
If the character has been vowel  additionally add a 'b' and the vowel to the new string and increment the index into the new string by 2.

You should be able to craft your code from this suggestion.